# How packets are forwarded from sender to receiver

Tags: ip

Suppose I have two computers A and B which are connected to same modem or they are getting internet from same ISP. When i search on google "What is my ip address?" It shows same ip address on both computer A and B 14.141.56.230. I want to know that if suppose a sender want to send data to computer A then how modem or router will recognize that this packet belongs to computer A not computer B as they both are having same ip address according to google.

Comment: I guess you should ask this on Server Fault, Stack Overflow is for programming.

Comment: You aren't using OSI in any way shape or form. [tag:osi] therefore has njava thing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the role of the [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). An external server cannot contact A or B directly: A or B have to contact the server first, so that the NAT knows how to treat the packets received by the external server.

In particular, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Translation_of_the_endpoint) should be interesting:

> When a computer on the private (internal) network sends an IPv4 packet to the external network, the NAT device replaces the internal IP address in the source field of the packet header (sender's address) with the external IP address of the NAT device. PAT may then assign the connection a port number from a pool of available ports, inserting this port number in the source port field (much like the post office box number), and forwards the packet to the external network. The NAT device then makes an entry in a translation table containing the internal IP address, original source port, and the translated source port. Subsequent packets from the same connection are translated to the same port number.

So the idea is that A is trying an external server E. When the message from A reaches the router R of A, then R changes the source IP of the packet, assigns it a port P, and sends this request to E. R remembers that it has assigned this port P to A. When E answers to R on port P, the router translates this back and forwards the packet to A.

It also means that E cannot contact A directly. A has to initiate the connection. Now consider the case where both A and E are behind a NAT; both of them would need to initiate the connection, which is not possible directly. To find a solution for that, you would need to look into [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching).

Comment: I request you to explain it in detail